# How to deal with randomly generated post request parameters in Jmeter Scripts?

Tags: jmeter

I am writing jmeter scripts for my web-based application. I am using firefox-firebug to watch POST request parameters. I could successfully write login page scripts because it had only "username" and "password" parameters.

But, after logging into the web application, I realized that, there are randomly generated required parameters which are sent along with the post request.

So, I am trying to find out the way to deal with these parameters.
Please let me know, if you have dealt with this situation.

Example: These are my post request parameters:

> externalId=971&submit.go=Go&submit.go=&013f57c77c2a%3A6eed%3A1b320be7=105f230e-9f86-40f8-9473-215975812128

Where `**013f57c77c2a%3A6eed%3A1b320be7**` parameter and it's value are generated differently each time.
I don't know how to define this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. You can use List Extractor(Regular Expression Extractor). 
You can define any pattern as per your criteria. 
for example regex patter is : input type="hidden" name="([^"]+?)" value="([^"]+?)"

Step2) Use Beanshell pre processor with this script.

```
            log.info("=====================");

             count =  Integer.valueOf (vars.getObject("hiddenList_matchNr") ) ;

            log.info("Number of hidden fields in previous sampler: " + count);



            for (i=1; i <= count; i++) { 
                paramName = vars.getObject("hiddenList_"+ i + "_g1");
                paramVal = vars.getObject("hiddenList_"+ i + "_g2");  
                log.info("Adding request parameter: " + paramName + " = " + paramVal);
                sampler.addArgument(paramName, paramVal);
            } 

            log.info("=====================");
```